# Missing data on particular date

Tags: mysql

mysql query to find data entry not present in table for particular date

I wish to find particular fridays date whose entru is not present in the table

Comment: Consider handling the logic of 'missing' data in application code.

Comment: If you are incapable to explain your problem clearly, you can't count with useful answers in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the things that exist in the data. So to find missing dates, you can create a table with all dates in your desired date range and make a query which selects those dates that do not exists in your other table.